# Creating project for reading data from gps device

Tags: jakarta-ee

i m beginner in this,please help me,Sir i want to create a web-project which read the data from gps device and display on the screen how i proceed,

Answer (score 0):

The GPS reading will need to be handled server side.  There are many consumer libraries for web enabling projects like this, here's a good place to start.

http://code.google.com/p/webduino/

If you need something more robust for a commercial environment, I know that there are a variety of Ethernet and USB enabled PIC microprocessors.

http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2504&redirects=ethernet